# grep a pattern and find the last word of the line

Tags: bash, shell, grep

Im trying to search through a file that only contains sequences of four words per line ie. the file looks like

```
walked the dog fast
jumped the moon high
on my nothing sun
on my not grass
```

and my code looks like

```
LINE=$(grep "^$PREV_THREE $PREV_TWO $PREV_ONE" $INPUT_FILE)
NEXT_WORD="${LINE##* }"
```

I use `$PREV_THREE $PREV_TWO $PREV_ONE` as the three words to indicate which fourth word to get from a specific line. My issue is that when `$PREV_THREE $PREV_TWO $PREV_ONE` equals `on my not`  it sets `NEXT_WORD` equal to `sun` instead of `grass`. Is there an elegant way to Grep the first three words to find a **perfect match** and then set next to the fourth word? Instead of what I have above which just finds an occurrence of my pattern.

Comment: Use `grep "^$PREV_THREE $PREV_TWO $PREV_ONE " $INPUT_FILE` with a trailing space

Answer (score 2):

It is easier to use a single `awk` command for this:

```sh
awk -v p='$PREV_THREE $PREV_TWO $PREV_ONE ' '$0 ~ p {print $4}' "$INPUT_FILE"

grass
```

btw your `grep` can also have a trailing space after last search word to make sure you don't match partial word. Consider this `gnu grep`:

```
grep -oP "^$PREV_THREE $PREV_TWO $PREV_ONE \K.+" $INPUT_FILE

grass
```